# Super sophisticated game information web application

Tags: java, spring, jsp

Considering I've got an exam on Spring tomorrow, I figured you could review a small example application I whipped together as preparation (and as such, I'd prefer the emphasis to be on Spring-related concepts).

Its functionality is straightforward: you start with a list of 3 games and you can edit or view its details, both which will lead to a different page. The former will allow you to update its description while also providing validation on the field.

Any suggestions?

### `GameController`

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/games")
public class GameController {
    @Autowired
    private IGameRepository gameRepository;

    @Autowired
    private GameValidator gameValidator;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("games", gameRepository.getGames());
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/details/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String details(Model model, @PathVariable("id") int id){
        Game game = gameRepository.getGameById(id);
        model.addAttribute("currentGame", game);
        return "details";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String edit(Model model, @PathVariable("id") int id){
        Game game = gameRepository.getGameById(id);
        model.addAttribute("edit_game_form", game);
        return "edit";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView update(@ModelAttribute("edit_game_form") @Valid Game game, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model){
        gameRepository.updateGame(game);

        gameValidator.validate(game, bindingResult);
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            return new ModelAndView("edit", "edit_game_form", game);
        }

        model.addAttribute("games", gameRepository.getGames());
        return new ModelAndView("index");
    }
}
```

### `Game`

```java
public class Game {
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String description;

    public Game(){ }

    public Game(int id, String title, String description) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }   
}
```

### `GameRepository`

```java
public class GameRepository implements IGameRepository{
    private List<Game> games = new ArrayList<>();

    public GameRepository(){
        games.add(new Game(1, "League of Legends", "fun game")); 
        games.add(new Game(5, "Call of Duty 4", "awesome game")); 
        games.add(new Game(4, "Farmville", "gtfo")); 
    }

    @Override
    public List<Game> getGames() {
        return games;
    }

    @Override
    public Game getGameById(int id) {
        for(Game game : games){
            if(game.getId() == id){
                return game;
            }
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("This id is not found");
    }

    @Override
    public void updateGame(Game game) {
        Iterator<Game> it = games.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            Game currentGame = it.next();

            if(currentGame.getId() == game.getId()){
                it.remove();
                break;
            }
        }

        games.add(game);
    }
}
```

### `IGameRepository`

```java
public interface IGameRepository {
    public List<Game> getGames();
    public Game getGameById(int id);
    public void updateGame(Game game);
}
```

### `GameValidator`

```java
public class GameValidator implements Validator {
    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> type) {
        return type == Game.class;
    }

    /* Arbitrary restrictions on the description:
        - Between 5 and 25 characters
        - Cannot contain a number
    */
    @Override
    public void validate(Object o, Errors errors) {
        Game game = (Game) o;

        String description = game.getDescription();
        if(description.length() < 5 || description.length() > 25){
            errors.rejectValue("description", "TODO:localization", "Stay within the boundaries");
        }

        if(description.matches(".*\\d.*")){
            errors.rejectValue("description", "TODO:localization", "NO NUMBERS!");
        }
    }
}
```

### ApplicationContext

```html
<bean id="gameRepository" class="domain.GameRepository" /> 
<bean id="gameValidator" class="domain.GameValidator" />
```

### Index.jsp

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Overview</title>
    </head>

    <spring:url value="/games/details/" var="detailsUrl" />
    <spring:url value="/games/edit/" var="editUrl" />

    <body>
        <h2>Games</h2>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <th> Id </th>
                <th> Title </th>
                <th> Description </th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <c:forEach items="${games}" var="game" varStatus="status">
                    <tr>
                        <td>${game.id}</td>
                        <td>${game.title}</td>
                        <td>${game.description}</td>
                        <td><a href="${detailsUrl}${game.id}.htm">Details</a></td>
                        <td><a href="${editUrl}${game.id}.htm">Edit</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

### Details.jsp

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Details - ${currentGame.title}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> Details for ${currentGame.title} </h1>

        <p>
            Description: ${currentGame.description}
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

### Edit.jsp

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Edit - ${currentGame.title}</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <style>
            .error { color: red; }
        </style>

        <h1>Update game information</h1>

        <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="edit_game_form">
            <form:errors path="*" cssClass="error" element="div"/>
            <form:hidden path="title" />
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Description:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <form:input path="description" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <form:errors path="description" cssClass="error" />
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">
                        <input type="submit" value="Update" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

#### `Game`

In the code you shared, you never use the setters of the `Game` class. How about making its fields `final` and removing the setters? Immutable things are simple, robust, and great. It's best to make everything immutable as much as you can.

Also, do you really need the empty constructor?

#### `GameRepository`

In `getGameById` and `updateGame` you iterate over a list of games. How about using a `Map` of `id -> Game` instead? It would seem a lot more natural, and at the same time more efficient.

#### Formatting

Overall the code is well readable. The one thing where you violate the standard is spaces around braces and parentheses:

> ```
> for(Game game : games){
>     if(game.getId() == id){
> ```

The standard (Eclipse does it with `Control-Shift-f`) would be:

```
for (Game game : games) {
    if (game.getId() == id) {
```

Comment: What would the `Map` be mapping exactly? Those setters aren't needed indeed, I just did a quick generate code in netbeans. The empty constructor is needed for Spring, something to do when I submit the form. I assume it's used to construct a new object and then fill its fields with reflection.

Comment: `Map` of `id -> Game`. I'm not familiar with spring-web, but "regular" spring dependency injection supports initialization with contructor-args not only with setters. I prefer using immutable fields and initializing in constructor, as that way you *know* that the constructed object is complete.

Comment: The Map would be `Map<Integer, Game>` and I was just thinking the same thing about that

Comment: Ah, like that. It doesn't feel very right to make the link between `id` and `Game` so loose. It's an interesting approach though, I'll keep it in mind. I see what you mean with the DI. I'm not sure if that's an option but I'll take a look at it later.

Comment: That link already exists in your code. Using a Map would make it easier to see for readers, making your code more intuitive, and at the same time more efficient. In any case, the mapping is in the private implementation of the class, so it's a hidden internal detail. I don't see anything wrong with it.

Answer (score 6):

I think you shouldn't declare your beans in the XML configuration if you can eeasily avoid it. Just annotate GameRepository and GameValidator with `@Repository` and `@Component` respectively, just like you have annotated GameController with `@Controller`. (See [about the different annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827752/whats-the-difference-between-component-repository-service-annotations-in).)

Then, I definitely second janos's comment about using a Map. Much more readable and conventional.

Next, you don't need to declare methods as `public` in IGameRepository. That's the only kind of a method an interface can define, so it's redundant. No harm done, but anyway. I find it a bit more clear when you leave the extra keywords out.

Finally, I don't know what topics your exam covers, but I'd definitely practice Spring Security and try creating a login form and different users so that some could both edit and view the games, whereas others could only view them. And learn the details about a Spring bean life cycle.

Comment: I was under the impression that the XML beans were a big plus for spring because it allows you to change behaviour on the fly. Is this incorrect? I'll take the other remarks with me for future purposes (for feedback: the exam happened to be extremely similar to this exercise I whipped up so that went awesome).

Comment: I don't think there's much that you can do with XML that you couldn't do with annotations, and since you were already using annotations, I'd find it consistent if you used annotations all the way. That being said, I believe they both have their uses, but it doesn't look like this particular case would benefit from an XML configuration in any way. The differences have been discussed a lot at StackOverflow -- for example:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698795/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428439/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182393/